# Parallel Multiple ImageGenerator for Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, keras

I have a Keras model that requires to use multiple `ImageGenerator` to feed the data from multiple sources (but the model still has only 1 input).

I have created a function that can do that (in practical I use 5-6 generators)

```
def multiple_generator(batch_size):
    genX1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./directory1',
                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                              batch_size=batch_size//2,
                                              class_mode='categorical')
    genX2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./directory2',
                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                              batch_size=batch_size//2,
                                              class_mode='categorical')
    while True:
               X1i = genX1.next()
               X2i = genX2.next()
               yield np.concatenate([X1i[0],X2i[0]],axis = 0),\
                     np.concatenate([X1i[1],X2i[1]],,axis = 0)
```

But when start training, the training time is much longer than using single generator. For instance, in single generator, it only takes 120s per epoch, regardless the `batch_size`, but when using `multiple_generator`, `batch_size = 64` takes 5 minutes, 128 takes 12 minutes per epoch.

I think that the task of iterate multiple generator may slow down the training time and I think of parallel the function like this:

```
def multiple_generator(batch_size):
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    genX1 = pool.apply(train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./directory1',
                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                              batch_size=batch_size//2,
                                          class_mode='categorical'))
    genX2 = pool.apply(train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./directory2',
                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                              batch_size=batch_size//2,
                                              class_mode='categorical'))
    while True:
               X1i = genX1.next()
               X2i = genX2.next()
               yield np.concatenate([X1i[0],X2i[0]],axis = 0),\
                     np.concatenate([X1i[1],X2i[1]],,axis = 0)
```

But it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-2d1d4ddfacf1>", line 4, in <module>
    class_mode='categorical'))
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 259, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/cngc3/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I don't have much experience on working with management of multiprocess, do you have any solution for this? Other strategy on speeding up the generator is always welcome. Thank you very much